# build script returned non-zero exit code 2 netlify

Tags: netlify

I keep getting an error when trying to build my project with Netlify. I have the project linked to a Github repo, and am trying to setup Continuous Integration. My build command is set to CI= false npm run build as seen in the image [Build command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAMAz.png). This is a React App, does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
5:42:41 PM: Build ready to start
5:43:12 PM: build-image version: d7b3dbfb0846505993c9a131894d1858074c90b4 (focal)
5:43:12 PM: build-image tag: v4.10.1
5:43:12 PM: buildbot version: 7e449fda4d95fa42451b88186ca7054116649237
5:43:12 PM: Building without cache
5:43:12 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
5:43:12 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
5:43:12 PM: git clone https://github.com/atrain42/prismal
5:43:12 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
5:43:12 PM: Parsing package.json dependencies
5:43:13 PM: Starting build script
5:43:13 PM: Installing dependencies
5:43:13 PM: Python version set to 2.7
5:43:14 PM: Downloading and installing node v16.17.0...
5:43:14 PM: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.17.0/node-v16.17.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
5:43:14 PM: Computing checksum with sha256sum
5:43:14 PM: Checksums matched!
5:43:17 PM: Now using node v16.17.0 (npm v8.15.0)
5:43:17 PM: Started restoring cached build plugins
5:43:17 PM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
5:43:17 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.2, read from environment
5:43:18 PM: Using ruby version 2.7.2
5:43:18 PM: Using PHP version 8.0
5:43:18 PM: No npm workspaces detected
5:43:18 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
5:43:18 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
5:43:18 PM: Installing NPM modules using NPM version 8.15.0
5:43:19 PM: npm WARN config tmp This setting is no longer used.  npm stores temporary files in a special
5:43:19 PM: npm WARN config location in the cache, and they are managed by
5:43:19 PM: npm WARN config     [`cacache`](http://npm.im/cacache).
5:43:19 PM: npm WARN config tmp This setting is no longer used.  npm stores temporary files in a special
5:43:19 PM: npm WARN config location in the cache, and they are managed by
5:43:19 PM: npm WARN config     [`cacache`](http://npm.im/cacache).
5:43:23 PM: npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
5:43:25 PM: npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
5:43:30 PM: added 1465 packages, and audited 1466 packages in 11s
5:43:30 PM: 209 packages are looking for funding
5:43:30 PM:   run `npm fund` for details
5:43:30 PM: 6 high severity vulnerabilities
5:43:30 PM: To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
5:43:30 PM:   npm audit fix --force
5:43:30 PM: Run `npm audit` for details.
5:43:30 PM: NPM modules installed
5:43:30 PM: npm WARN config tmp This setting is no longer used.  npm stores temporary files in a special
5:43:30 PM: npm WARN config location in the cache, and they are managed by
5:43:30 PM: npm WARN config     [`cacache`](http://npm.im/cacache).
5:43:30 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
5:43:30 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
5:43:30 PM: Installing Go version 1.17 (requested 1.17)
5:43:34 PM: unset GOOS;
5:43:34 PM: unset GOARCH;
5:43:34 PM: export GOROOT='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.17.linux.amd64';
5:43:34 PM: export PATH="/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.17.linux.amd64/bin:${PATH}";
5:43:34 PM: go version >&2;
5:43:34 PM: export GIMME_ENV="/opt/buildhome/.gimme/env/go1.17.linux.amd64.env"
5:43:34 PM: go version go1.17 linux/amd64
5:43:34 PM: Installing missing commands
5:43:34 PM: Verify run directory
5:43:35 PM: ​
5:43:35 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:43:35 PM:   Netlify Build                                                 
5:43:35 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:43:35 PM: ​
5:43:35 PM: ❯ Version
5:43:35 PM:   @netlify/build 27.18.1
5:43:35 PM: ​
5:43:35 PM: ❯ Flags
5:43:35 PM:   baseRelDir: true
5:43:35 PM:   buildId: 63239c5178b23e0ab52168b5
5:43:35 PM:   deployId: 63239c5178b23e0ab52168b7
5:43:35 PM: ​
5:43:35 PM: ❯ Current directory
5:43:35 PM:   /opt/build/repo
5:43:35 PM: ​
5:43:35 PM: ❯ Config file
5:43:35 PM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
5:43:35 PM: ​
5:43:35 PM: ❯ Context
5:43:35 PM:   production
5:43:35 PM: ​
5:43:35 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:43:35 PM:   1. Build command from Netlify app                             
5:43:35 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:43:35 PM: ​
5:43:35 PM: $ CI=false npm run build
5:43:35 PM: npm WARN config tmp This setting is no longer used.  npm stores temporary files in a special
5:43:35 PM: npm WARN config location in the cache, and they are managed by
5:43:35 PM: npm WARN config     [`cacache`](http://npm.im/cacache).
5:43:35 PM: > prismal@0.1.0 build
5:43:35 PM: > react-scripts build
5:43:36 PM: Creating an optimized production build...
5:43:38 PM: Failed to compile.
5:43:38 PM: 
5:43:38 PM: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Navbar/MobileNavigation' in '/opt/build/repo/src/components'
5:43:38 PM: ​
5:43:38 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:43:38 PM:   "build.command" failed                                        
5:43:38 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:43:38 PM: ​
5:43:38 PM:   Error message
5:43:38 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: CI=false npm run build (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
5:43:38 PM: ​
5:43:38 PM:   Error location
5:43:38 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
5:43:38 PM:   CI=false npm run build
5:43:38 PM: ​
5:43:38 PM:   Resolved config
5:43:38 PM:   build:
5:43:38 PM:     command: CI=false npm run build
5:43:38 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
5:43:38 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/build
5:43:38 PM:     publishOrigin: ui
5:43:38 PM: Caching artifacts
5:43:38 PM: Started saving node modules
5:43:38 PM: Finished saving node modules
5:43:38 PM: Started saving build plugins
5:43:38 PM: Finished saving build plugins
5:43:38 PM: Started saving pip cache
5:43:38 PM: Finished saving pip cache
5:43:38 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
5:43:38 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
5:43:38 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
5:43:38 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
5:43:38 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
5:43:39 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
5:43:39 PM: Started saving rust rustup cache
5:43:39 PM: Finished saving rust rustup cache
5:43:39 PM: Started saving go dependencies
5:43:39 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
5:43:40 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
5:43:40 PM: Creating deploy upload records
5:43:40 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
5:43:40 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2 (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-2)
5:43:40 PM: Finished processing build request in 28.448609241s
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a lot with this issue, I solved it upgrading the node version of netlify